# Using git filter-repo to clean up git history

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

I have a repository that used to be a monorepo, and used to have, let's say, some library, sitting under `common/shared/foo` subdirectory. Then some people decided to switch to microservices, so they basically made X copies of the repository, and in each of those just deleted all non-relevant files, moved `foo` contents on the root level (so what used to be under `common/shared/foo/src/` is now under `src/` etc.; and then just committed it as a single commit (later referred to as "big bang" commit). And then for about a year development occurred within those "mini" repos.

Now, I'd like to rewrite (clean up) history in such repositories, so I googled a bit and decided to use `git-filter-repo` for that. However I can't find a combination of options that would treat sub-histories differently: for commits PRIOR to a "big bang" it should only filter (leave in place) commits touching on the `common/shared/foo` subdirectory; and also for those commits leave all files from under this subdirectory to a root directory; and for all commits AFTER the "big bang" commit, it should just leave all "as is".

Is there a way to achieve this with `git filter-repo`? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the branches (or any refs) to work on with the [`--refs` option](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html) :

```
git branch that/point/in/time <commit sha>
git filter-repo --refs that/point/in/time ...
```

---

Once you have rewritten up to `that/point/in/time`, you can plug the recent history on top of the rewritten sequence :

```
# replace the commit that initially was that/point/in/time with the rewritten one :
git replace <previous sha> that/point/in/time

# run git filter-repo --force to rewrite the history of all branches as
# if they happened on top of the new commit :
git filter-repo --force
```

*note* : the above command will simply write a new chain of commits, with the content of each commit preserved as is. Inspect your history to see if you need to add some additional edits around the junction.

Comment: so then filter-repo will only re-write commits contained in the branch? Will try it out

Comment: I guess it kinda worked for pre-bigbang commits, but now I need to somehow re-write all the "post-bigbang" commit to be children of bigbang commit, to get to linear history

Comment: With that last command, I get: git-filter-repo: error: unrecognized arguments: --all

Comment: hmmm, I got mixed with other git commands. No `--all` for `git filter-repo` (it is the default)

Comment: thank you much @LeGec! I finally figure out why I had issues: I've set the "bigbang" ref to the commit where "splitting" happened, i.e. where there was already no code under "common/shared/foo" subfolder, I had to re-write history BEFORE that one. And second thing that might be relevant is whether there're any active HEADs apart from the `main` one

Comment: one more thing @LeGec, maybe you know: is there a way to "imprint" this "replacement" so the history would look like a proper one? currently it's based on `refs/replace` which I've never worked with and I am afraid it might put some of my colleagues off... thanks!

Comment: @62mkv: running `git filter-repo --force` after a replace should have done this "imprint" on your rewritten branch. Do you see any mention of a replaced commit when you inspect the history of your branch ?

Comment: yes, even after this command, I see the replace in the "packed-refs" file and also it is displayed (as "replace/commit-hash") labels on 3 commits in GitExtensions UI (those are basically all commits from HEAD to "bigbang" inclusively)

Comment: this is what "git replace" shows 

39d019ca91feeb7bfb9b6dfacafb8f027164b7af ((NULL)) -> 18d704d51cb2a1953ba64e1ace5f9d81c042aac3 (commit)
53c08ca84d952acbefc624e4c4d167cd66dcf9b2 ((NULL)) -> ee73ef29523accdd8011c0e3527f677de94b447f (commit)
93d1ff04bd9195c53234587e31eb0810cefe518c ((NULL)) -> c8b2c089e62c1de46912cb82c6e7047c6ee94052 (commit)

not sure if those ((NULL)) types are indicator of any wrongdoing...

Comment: Why does it modify commits hashes of commits before the `that/point/in/time`? The only thing it did not change is the initial commit and the few commits from the first merged branch. From the first merge commit (including) everything is changed.